# Wikipedia JSON API with PHP

Tags: php, json, api, parsing, wikipedia

I'm trying to get the content of wikipedia ( in Bulgarian language ) using it's API with the following code:

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://bg.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F&prop=revisions&rvprop=content");
```

The problem is that the result look like this:

```
........."*":"{{\u043a\u044a\u043c \u043f\u043e\u044f\u0441\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435|\u0421\u043e\u0444\u0438\u044f|\u0421\u043e\u0444\u0438\u044f (\u043f\u043e\u044f\u0441\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435)}}\n{{\u0421\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0449\u0435 \u0432 \u0411\u044a\u043b\u0433\u0430\u0440\u0438\u044f\n|
```

I'm getting this result even if I open the link in a browser. If I change the JSON to XML it works nice, but if the format is JSON, the content is "unreadable".

How I can get readable text? Or is there any other simple solution for parsing the paragraphs with its content from wikipedia?

Comment: Those are escaped unicode characters. If you parse the JSON into an object, it'll look fine.

Answer (score 2):

Content retured by server is JSON. use  [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)  function:

```
$Content_array=json_decode($content,true);
```